# How to subscribe a method to fire onchange and on a custom event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have a method setup to fire onChange with the following code:

```
var product = $('#selProduct:visible');
var note=$('#bbdata');

product.selectProduct({
    target: note,
    url: 'product.php',
    data: { ajax: true }
}).trigger('change'); // TO DO: to fire also on visibility change
```

Then I have a method where I make a div visible.

```
function show_product() {
    hide_group2();
    $("#product_zone2").show('fast', function(){
    $("selProduct").trigger('isVisibleProduct');// custom trigger event
    });
}
```

I want to change the method definition to fire also when I raise the custom event. How do I do that?

Comment: I cannot see where you bind the event handlers to any event....

Comment: It's the `.trigger('change');` call on the method postfix.

Comment: But that is firing the event, not binding the handler. You said *I want to change the method definition to fire also when I raise the custom event.* which somehow translates to: When I fire a custom event, the method should be executed. But which method do you want to change, which should be executed when a event happens? What is `selectProduct()` ?

Comment: I want to execute the `selectProduct` method when I raise `isVisibleProduct` event.

Comment: I don't have any other bind method. I don't know in how other way jQuery binds the selectProduct method to the onchange event, but it fires. Probably the method definition has something to do with it.

Comment: That is what I'm asking. What is `selectProduct()`? Have *you* defined it? Is it some method of a plugin? I have never seen a standard jQuery method that is named liked this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to link your desired function to any type of event (event custom).

```
myObject.bind('myEventName', function(){/*..*/});
```

or

```
myObject.bind('myEventName', myFunctionName);
```

then trigger with

```
myObject.trigger('myEventName');
```

---

If your case you could put

```
product.bind('isVisibleProduct', function(){
  this.selectProduct({
      target: note,
      url: 'product.php',
      data: { ajax: true }
  }).trigger('change'); // TO DO: to fire also on visibility change
});
```

Comment: `this.selectProduct({...])` I'm pretty sure this will run some error. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With this code

```
product.selectProduct({
    target: note,
    url: 'product.php',
    data: { ajax: true }
}).trigger('change');
```

are not binding `selectProduct()` to be fired on a `change` event. You just execute `selectProduct()` and then fire `change` on `product`. *Maybe* `selectProduct()` binds something to the `change` event. But without knowing what it does, it is hard to tell.

If you want to execute `selectProduct()` on the `change` event and your custom event, you have to bind an event handler to both events, like so:

```
product.bind('change isVisibleProduct', function() {
    $(this).productSelect({/* ...parameters here ... */});
});
```

Please clarify your question if this is not what you mean.

Comment: The 2nd part is good, however I am not so sure about the first assumption, as I don't have any other bind method that binds the selectProduct to the onchange event in the page. Probably the ajax method definition does, but not sure.

Comment: @Pentium10: The problem is that if `selectProduct()` itself binds some method, everytime you execute the function again, it will bind that method again (in addition!) which you don't want.

Comment: the event is called 'change', not 'onchange', try not to confuse them